Can't save/get Patterns' `post_content` attribute
I am currently successful at getting the WordPress patterns via the following query:
SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = 'wp_block'

Problem is, I realized post_content is empty, except for some patterns added a long time ago.

I checked MyPHPAdmin table, and its empty there, too (logically).

I tried to 'Export (the pattern) as JSON' and the post_content appears beautifully there! I suppose it's not taking it from the DB but wraps the content already rendered in the patterns page and exports the JSON with the content it has in the UI (or there is another table where I can get this post_content from?)

I tried saving the same way another block that hasn't got much logic in it, and saves its post_content perfectly. The main difference I found from the components that save the post_content is that they use a Save component, while the component that has the issue doesn't, since I render it from the server in my index.php:


<?php

/**
 * Register footer block
 */
function footer___register_block()
{
    register_block_type(__DIR__ . '/build', array(
        'render_callback' => 'render_footer_block'
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'footer___register_block');

/**
 * Render callback for the footer block
 *
 * @param array $attributes
 */
function render_footer_block($attributes)
{
    // Start rendering output
    $output = '<footer ' . wp_kses_data(get_block_wrapper_attributes()) . '>';
    // ...Rest of the footer content
    $output .= '</footer>';

    return $output;
}
?>

So, here is my index.js, where save returns null
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { Editor } from './Editor.js';
import metadata from '../block.json';

// Register the block
registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
    edit: Editor,
    save: () => null,
} );

I already tried adding the Save component and render it just like the others that save correctly the post_content, but this doesn't solve it.

I am looking at my wp_posts table in MyPHPAdmin, and seems like the post_content column is blank for posts after May, regardless of the post_type. Maybe it's a bigger issue than just the Patterns?

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you.

can you provide more context for how and where that component is used? Is this in an edit component or a save component or both? The create pattern option you showed opens a dialog with options but it's unclear what you chose

@TomJNowell what do you mean with 'where that component is used'? Since it's a footer, it's used everywhere and it works fine, except for when I save it as pattern. I added some info of the component folder structure and where is located in the project (is a Save/Edit Component).
YOU KNOW WHAT I just realized with your question, that I don't have a Save.js and index-client.js like on the other blocks. This is because I render it from the server (with the index.php file). Maybe the pattern looks for the Save component of the block and it's not finding it.

@TomJNowell About the 'Create Pattern' steps I followed, I just add a name, a categories (or none), and it throws the error in all possible combinations. I also mentioned I tried with other simpler blocks (also Save/Edit Components) and it saves fine, so I don't believe the problem comes from that dialog.

@TomJNowell I edited the question since I could resolve the React error. But I'm still having problems with the saving of post_content which I believe is a WordPress issue...

I asked because the react error implied certain types of calls that were nowhere to be seen in your code, and there was no connection between the registration of a block and the usage of the component you shared. All we have to go on is edit: Editor, where the Editor component is a blackbox with no information. Server rendered blocks should work fine with patterns so the lack of a save component is not the issue, it's likely from your last point that this has nothing to do with react or blocks if nothing after May has post content
